# What files do I need to push so that my changes are reflected in AOSP:?

Tags: android, android-source

I am new to Android Open Source Project (AOSP) and trying to build my own version of Android OS. Currently, I am trying to learn to modify the codes of Android 10 and trying to find whether it works or not. To do that, I have firstly added a few codes in "LocationManager" class in the framework. I just added some Log code to output some message in the code like in the below:

```
Log.i(TAG,"Lets see");
```

After that, I have built the code using the following code:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng aosp_x86-eng
make sdk
```

What should be my next step if I want to see whether my changes works or not in an Genymotion emulator device? I have been trying to understand some online sources but not understanding them totally. I have also been trying to use "adb sync" command and finding out the emulator not working. I have also pushed some files as well but no result. I would be glad if someone can direct me in the right path. Thanks in advance for your kind assistance. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the system image and then trying it out would be the ideal way, but here's a hacky approach: Replace xxx with the actual path intermediate.

```
adb root && adb remount

adb push out\target\product\xxx\system\framework\services.jar  /system/framework/
adb push out\target\product\xxx\system\framework\services.jar.prof  /system/framework
adb push out\target\product\xxx\system\framework\oat\arm64\services.art  /system/framework/oat/arm64/
adb push out\target\product\xxx\system\framework\oat\arm64\services.odex  /system/framework/oat/arm64/
adb push out\target\product\xxx\system\framework\oat\arm64\services.vdex  /system/framework/oat/arm64/

adb reboot
```

Comment: I have done that.....When I tried to reboot the emulator device, it is not booting up.

Comment: As I said, rebuilding the system image is the better option. But, regardless, please share the logcat during boot time and paste it on a service like pastebin.